# setting taxonomy term to bulk posts using ids

Tags: terms

Is there any way to insert a taxonomy term to different posts whose ids are known in bulk.  For example, suppose we have custom post types with ids 4522, 4524, 4526, 4528 and 4530; how can I insert a taxonomy term 'football' in taxonomy 'sports'.
Thanks
The code used in index.php

```
    <?php
$post_ids = [57542, 57544, 57546, 57548, 57550, 57552, 57554, 57556, 57558, 57562, 57564, 57566, 57169, 57192, 57189]; // array of post ID's
foreach ( $post_ids as $id ) {
    if ( !has_term( 'geography', 'objective-questions', $id ) ) // Check if term is not yet attached to post 
        wp_set_post_terms(
            $id, // Post ID
            'geography', // Term slug ( or can be term ID )
            'objective-questions', // Taxonomy name
            true // Only append the term, do not replace
        );
}?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand this correctly. You can simply just add your post ID's in an array and then use a `foreach` loop to loop through the ID's and checking whether or not they have the term to assign or not, and if not, assign the term to the post

```
$post_ids = [4522, 4524, 4526, 4528, 4530]; // array of post ID's
foreach ( $post_ids as $id ) {
    if ( !has_term( 'footbal', 'sports', $id ) ) // Check if term is not yet attached to post 
        wp_set_object_terms (
            $id, // Post ID
            'footbal', // Term slug ( or can be term ID )
            'sports', // Taxonomy name
            true, // Only append the term, do not replace
        );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But putting it in functions.php gives unexpected 'wp_set_post_terms' (T_STRING)

Comment: Hello Pieter, I tried it but somehow it does not work.

Comment: What exactly is happening or not happening?

Comment: These are custom post types and already published. I suppose that by putting this code in functions.php should append the new term to every post with the given ids. I used your code and saved it in functions.php and it did nothing. Neither it threw an error nor my posts got the term.

Comment: Just add the code in any template (*like `index.php`*), not `functions.php`, refresh the homepage, and it should be done. Remove the code afterwards

Comment: I tried it with index.php and I have added the real code I am using. it somehow does not produce any result.

Comment: My pleasure, enjoy :-)

Comment: Works like a charm. Just run the code in a test.php file inside of my theme folder. All post updated.